# Mongo CDC throws : BSONObjectTooLarge . How to ignore this and proceed further?

Tags: java, mongodb, cdc

I would liketo listen only to 3 collections in a database: c1, c2, c3. I was not able to figureout how to limit listening to these 3 collections only. Below is my code.

1. i would like to ignore this error and proceed further. How to do it? In this case the cursor itself is not getting created.
2. Like i said previously, is there a way to limit the listening to the collections `c1`, `c2` `c3` collections only?-- on the db side. Below code is listening to the full db and then filtering the collections on the java side.

```
        List<Bson> pipeline = singletonList(match(in("operationType", asList("insert", "delete", "update"))));
        MongoChangeStreamCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> cursor;
        String resumeTokenStr = getResumeTokenFromS3(cdcConfig);
        if (resumeTokenStr == null) {
            cursor = mongoClient.watch(pipeline).fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP).cursor();
        } else {
            BsonDocument resumeToken = BsonDocument.parse(resumeTokenStr);
            cursor = mongoClient.watch(pipeline).batchSize(1).maxAwaitTime(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).startAfter(resumeToken).fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP).cursor();
        }
        return cursor;
```

The above code throws the below error

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 10334 (BSONObjectTooLarge): 'BSONObj size: 16795345 (0x10046D1) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: { _data: "826337A73B0000000A2B022C0100296E5A1004B317A529F739433BA840730515AC0EAC46645F6964006462624E8146E0FB000934F6560004" }' on server crm-mongo-report01.prod.phenom.local:27017. The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1664707966, "i": 25}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "BSONObj size: 16795345 (0x10046D1) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: { _data: \"826337A73B0000000A2B022C0100296E5A1004B317A529F739433BA840730515AC0EAC46645F6964006462624E8146E0FB000934F6560004\" }", "code": 10334, "codeName": "BSONObjectTooLarge", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1664707966, "i": 26}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": {"base64": "NZDJKhCse19Eud88kNh7XRWRgas=", "subType": "00"}}, "keyId": 7113062344413937666}}}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:198)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:413)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:337)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:644)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:240)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$OperationCountTrackingConnection.command(DefaultServer.java:345)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.createReadCommandAndExecute(CommandOperationHelper.java:232)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.lambda$executeRetryableRead$4(CommandOperationHelper.java:214)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$2(OperationHelper.java:575)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:600)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$3(OperationHelper.java:574)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:600)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(OperationHelper.java:573)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.lambda$executeRetryableRead$5(CommandOperationHelper.java:211)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:65)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeRetryableRead(CommandOperationHelper.java:217)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeRetryableRead(CommandOperationHelper.java:197)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AggregateOperationImpl.execute(AggregateOperationImpl.java:195)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ChangeStreamOperation$1.call(ChangeStreamOperation.java:347)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ChangeStreamOperation$1.call(ChangeStreamOperation.java:343)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:538)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ChangeStreamOperation.execute(ChangeStreamOperation.java:343)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.ChangeStreamOperation.execute(ChangeStreamOperation.java:58)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:191)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ChangeStreamIterableImpl.execute(ChangeStreamIterableImpl.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ChangeStreamIterableImpl.cursor(ChangeStreamIterableImpl.java:174)
    at com.company.cdc.services.CDCMain.getCursorAtResumeToken(CdcServiceMain.java:217)
```

line 217 points to the line :  `cursor = mongoClient.watch(pipeline).batchSize(1).maxAwaitTime(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).startAfter(resumeToken).fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP).cursor();`

Comment: Seems like the outcome depends on what `resumeToken` contains.

Comment: Max. size of 16793600 Byte (16 MiBYte) is a fix limit. Make your documents smaller, there is no other way. If you need to store bigger documents, then see [GridFS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/)

Comment: We should atleast be able to ignore such large rows and proceed further. how? --I am trying to find out. Also, i think the error is not coming from the collections I own. in the above code if we can somehow mention the `collections` of interest in the `pipeline` object -- I think the issue can be fixed. But i couldnt know how to do it. Any help?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i went through the GridFS documentation. What is not clear is how to use it in the context of CDC. The document shared is more wrt finding a document. Even google doesnt help. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i ended up solving the problem. (just incase somebody else is searching for solution to-this problem)

1. removed `FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP` when creating the cursor. So now my code looks like `cursor = mongoClient.watch(pipeline).batchSize(20000).cursor();` --Now this avoided the gigantic column that may endup in the document which was eventually error-ing out. This worked.
2. In my case i didnt have to listen to the collection updates which had this bad data. So i modified my cursor to listen only on the databases and collections of my interest --instead of listening on the entire database and then ignoring the unwanted collections later. Below is the code
3. When writing to the destination i had done bulk lookup on mongo db, constructed the full document and then written it --This approach of lazy lookup reduced a lot of memory footprint of the java program.

```
    private List<Bson> generatePipeline(CdcConfigs cdcConfig) {
        List<String> whiteListedCollections = getWhitelistedCollection(cdcConfig);
        List<String> whiteListedDbs = getWhitelistedDbs(cdcConfig);
        log.info("whitelisted dbs:" + whiteListedDbs + " coll:" + whiteListedCollections);
        List<Bson> pipeline;
        if (whiteListedDbs.size() > 0)
            pipeline = singletonList(match(and(
                    in("ns.db", whiteListedDbs),
                    in("ns.coll", whiteListedCollections),
                    in("operationType", asList("insert", "delete", "update")))));
        else
            pipeline = singletonList(match(and(
                    in("ns.coll", whiteListedCollections),
                    in("operationType", asList("insert", "delete", "update")))));
        return pipeline;
    }

    private MongoChangeStreamCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> getCursorAtResumeToken(CdcConfigs cdcConfig, MongoClient mongoClient) {
        List<Bson> pipeline = generatePipeline(cdcConfig);
        MongoChangeStreamCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> cursor;
        String resumeTokenStr = getResumeTokenFromS3(cdcConfig);
        if (resumeTokenStr == null) {
//            cursor = mongoClient.watch(pipeline).fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP).cursor();
            cursor = mongoClient.watch(pipeline).batchSize(20000).cursor();
            log.warn("RESUME TOKEN IS NULL. READING CDC FROM CURRENT TIMESTAMP FROM MONGO DB !!! ");
        } else {
            BsonDocument resumeToken = BsonDocument.parse(resumeTokenStr);
            cursor = mongoClient.watch(pipeline).batchSize(20000).maxAwaitTime(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES).startAfter(resumeToken).cursor();
//            cursor = mongoClient.watch(pipeline).startAfter(resumeToken).fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP).cursor();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

The solutions available sofar are more inclined towards python code. So it was a challange translating them into Java.

Answer (score 0):

My case is a little bit different. I have a trigger used to align documents from a collection to another, with the option to include the fullDocument in the change event. Problem is that the [metadata](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/insert/#mongodb-data-insert) added to the event, combined with the fullDocument, exceeds the BSON max size (16MB).

I solved removing the fullDocument from the trigger and getting the document from the collection itself performing an aggregate:

```
   collection1.aggregate([
            {$match: {_id: changeEvent.documentKey._id}},
            { $merge: { into: "collection", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
          ]);
```